# Wing options for Lakeview Manor

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So, I have built the Lakeview Manor house. So far I have the storage room for the north wing and the armory for the east wing. For the west wing, I can choose between Enchantment Tower, Greenhouse and Bedrooms. I have a couple of questions regarding this:

- Is it possible to replace the additions I already built for the north and east wing with one of the other options? If it isn't in vanilla, is there a mod that will allow me to do that?
- Why would I need a bedroom as my west wing addition? Doesn't the main house have enough beds for wife, two kids, the stewart and the bard? Will I need to build the Bedroom addition in order to get all of those?
- Related to this: do I have to plan ahead before getting the 'Remodel House into Entryway' addition? The bed in the Small House is currently being used by my wife Aela; I have one child, a stewart and a bard. And even though Aela keeps bitching about the bandit attacks, I don't want her to have to sleep on the floor...

Comment: You can delete wings by going meta. Load the game without the Hearthfire DLC, and your Hearthfire DLC things will be removed if you save. That means that then you can load Hearthfire and you can rebuild your house. Problem is, you have to rebuild all rooms (and anything you might have saved in them is lost). I know this isn't a good method, but it's possible, provided you accept taking a major loss on your items/house

Comment: @Oak That's metal. I spent a fortune on that stupid place, only so that I could marry, adopt a child and have that child take my beloved Meeko as a pet ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can only change your choice of a wing before you build the doors from the main hall, after that the wing is fixed... of course, with the right mod, anything is be possible.
2. Without the "Bedroom Wing" your house will be able to have a double bed in the East Bedroom and two single beds in the West Bedroom.

   Your spouse gets preferential use of the East Upstairs Room. Children get preferential use of the West Upstairs room.  Staff get what's left, if anything.

   If you build the West Wing bedroom, 3 more beds are available: a double & 2 singles. Family will then take those beds, leaving the upstairs beds for your staff. (Bard, Housecarl & Steward).

   Since you already have 2 of the 3 "Outside Deck" wings, (Storage Room & Armory) you might as well give your family a complete wrap around deck by building the bedrooms. Just think of the parties you could host out there!
3. Your wife will probably evict the staff member from the Eastern Upstairs Bedroom.

FWIW: I've never actually built the bed in the "Small House", preferring instead to save the materials on things that just don't go in entryway...

FWIW #2: If you have [skyrim-dawnguard](/questions/tagged/skyrim-dawnguard) and choose to side with the Volkihar Clan, you'll be able to build another place to sleep in that nook on the south wall of the basement's east room.

Comment: Thank you! So the Bedroom isn't needed for full family + staff? Because I really want that Enchantment Tower ... °v°

Comment: @MoritzLost Correct.  Family *need* beds & chests.  Staff can stand around all night looking forlorn. - Towers do supply easy access to the nest on the north end of the main hall's roof.  And the manikin in the Enchanting tower is a convenient place to store Ahzidal's armor...